# Proving that a set is closed.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be compact, metric, connected and locally connected space and let $M\subseteq X$ closed and connected.  Suppose $a,b,p\in M$ are non-cut points of $X$.

I showed that $M\setminus \{p\}$ is connected.  Now I would like to show that $M\setminus\{p\}$ is closed.

Maybe some of the properties of X are not necessary.

If this is true, can anyone help me prove it?

Comment: Is  the unit disk minus the point of origin closed?

Answer (score 0):

$M \setminus \{p\}$ will only be closed if $p$ is an isolated point of $M$, and these don't exist as $M$ is connected. So you cannot prove it's closed (unless $M = \{p\}$, trivially).